# How to display time in local timezone without "Text content does not match server-rendered HTML" in Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm learning Next.js by creating a blog with it. I'm trying to format a static ISO time string (creation time of blog posts) to the local timezone of the user.

```js
<div className='post-time'>
    Posted at {new Date(post.frontmatter.date).toLocaleString()}
</div>
```

However, this gives me an error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.
```

I have tried to turn this into a state as the documentation suggested, but the error persists. I'm pretty sure there's a simple solution I'm not seeing here.
How can I change this to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems I handled useState incorrectly. This is how I solved it:

```js
const [time, setTime] = useState(post.frontmatter.date)
    useEffect(() => {
        setTime(new Date(post.frontmatter.date).toLocaleString())
    })
```